# Saiyans but plausible

Tags: biology, humans, aliens, humanoid, reproduction

Sayans are an alien species of humanoids, yet they look completely human with small exceptions

Saiyans are born from a planet called Vegeta, the plant planet.They have a tail and are able to change color of their hairs when their bodies are flowing with "power"

They can get more powerful momentarily by either flooding their bodies with hormones or some other mechanics...how they get stronger is not the subject of the question.

Apparently humans and saiyans are related,because they can create hybrids...just like Neanderthals and sapiens.

The question is, how can two creatures so distant procreate?

Comment: This sounds more like a question about an "in universe" explanation than a worldbuilding problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saiyans could be descended from a prehistoric population of humans that were transported to another planet by ancient aliens, and are still close enough to Homo Sapiens in order to interbreed.